# Namespace and Fixture is Empty in Visual NUnit

Tags: nunit, visual-studio-extensions

I am new to NUnit. When I am run the test cases using NUnit GUI its working perfectly, but when I use Visual NUnit from View->Other Windows->Visual NUnit, only the project is loaded. The Namespace and the Fixture in it are empty. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Visual NUnit not populated]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and manage to resolve it as follows:

1. Set the NUnit test project as my startup project.
2. Build the entire solution.
3. Click the "Run" button without entering a Namespace or Fixture field.
4. The fields should now become populated.
5. Hit "Run" again to kick all the tests off.